# how can return formula field as Date/Time

Tags: formula

I want to use this formula field in workflow rule time trigger but i am getting error-

**Error:**

> Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data
>   type (Date/Time).

formula field code is below.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P1"),  Now()- 0.03109,  

IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P2"),Now()- 0.03800), 

"false"  )  )
```

Comment: "false" is not a Date/Time, you need to fix your FALSE scenario and return null or another valid Date/Time

Comment: Hi Bachovski,
Whether i am returning null than also got same error
Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time).

Comment: what do you want to return in false case scenario?

Comment: Try this `IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P1"), Now() - 0.03109,
IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P2"), Now() - 0.03800, null), null)`

Comment: If condition will be true than return Date/Time.If false than it should also return flase in Date/Time type

Comment: False is not a Date/Time, it's a Boolean value. You can only set an actual Date/Time value or null (nothing) in a Date/Time field.

Comment: i am checking now your above code

Comment: Hi Boris after using this 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P1"), Now() - 0.03109, IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P2"), Now() - 0.03800, null), null)

Now getting this Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Comment: Hi Boris is there any other solution for this scenario please share .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
> IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P1"), Now() - 0.03109,
> IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority_Time__c, "P2"), Now() - 0.03800, null))
```

Comment: Hi Night 
Your above solution is working
Thanks Night